# Python : Argparse take default value from json file if not passed in command line

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a script with command-line arguments that I need to modify. I want to make `-x`, `-s`, and `-e` mandatory, while -m should be optional. If -m is not passed, it should take the value from a JSON file. Each -x value will have a separate file with the same name under `/opt/abc_m.json`. Note that every input of `-x` will have a file placed under `/opt`. Invalid `-x` options will exit the code.

**The contents of abc_m.json are as follows**

```
{
  "memory": "'12000",
  "container_vcpus": "2",
  "container_memory": "14336"
}
```

**The argparse code is as follows**

```
parser.add_argument('-x', dest='shops', metavar='SHOP', type=str, nargs='+',
                    help='shop name (eg "abc_m") for which to process')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', dest='start', required=False, metavar='START', type=str, default=None,
                    help='Starting  date as in integer in YYYYMMDD format')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--end', dest='end', metavar='END', type=str, required=False, default=None,
                    help='Ending  date as in integer in YYYYMMDD format')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--memory', dest='memory', metavar='MEMORY', type=int, required=False, default=None,
                    help='Memory allocation in MB')
```

I am not sure is it possible to parse `json` to get `argparse` default value

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value afterwards and read it if necessary

```
parser.add_argument('-m', '--memory', dest='memory', metavar='MEMORY', type=int, required=False, default=None, help='Memory allocation in MB')
memory = parser.parse_args().memory

if memory is None:
    with open('abc_m.json') as js:
        memory = int(json.load(js)['memory'])
```

Comment: checking above code